# How to extract the all the user defined functions from elf file using c programming

Tags: c, elf

I have a source code with multiple files.How to extract the file & function details from elf using c program

Comment: First of all the executable files do not contain any source code at all. And if it doesn't have any debug information attached then you can't even get information about functions and source-file locations either. The code in an executable file or a shared library is just one or more binary blobs.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  
can i use file and function pointers along with a structure similar to symbol table, so that i can call a particular function in a particular file dynamically

Comment: @MartinSebastian If you can compile your source code into shared libraries, then it's easy to look up functions and call them using [dlopen and dlsym](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). See the example in that man page.

Answer (score 2):

> How to extract the file & function details from elf using c program.

This requires non-trivial amount of programming. There are libraries which can help: [libelf](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Libelf) and [libdwarf](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libdwarf/). Or you can read sources for [readelf](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/readelf.html).

Comment: can i use file and function pointers along with a structure similar to symbol table, so that i can call a particular function in a particular file dynamically

Comment: @MartinSebastian Your comment doesn't make sense. If you have a function pointer, *of course* you can call it -- that's what a function pointer *is* -- something you can call.

Comment: i do have a structure like this                                                                    struct {
    char *filename;
    char *funcname;
    int (*funcptr)();
} symtab[] = {
    { "filename1", "one_func", one_func },
    { "filename2", "two_func", two_func },
};                                                                                                                   and a symbol table above. I need to check whether a particular function is present in any of files from function table and execute that one